# Asp.Net Web API List model is returning List<List>>

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, postman

I am calling a third party API through ajax call and return the data with a Model object.

```
public class AddressModel
{
     public List<Address> address {get; set;}
     public List<Component> components {get; set;}
}

public class Address
{
    public string address1 { get; set;}
    public string address2 { get; set;}
    public string postalCode { get; set;}
}
```

Api Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult GetAddress(string id)
{
     ** code **
     var addr = _service.GetAddressById(id);
     return Ok(addr);
}

public AddressModel GetAddressById(string id)
{
    ** code **

    HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(uri).Result;
    return response.Content.ReadAsAsync<AddressModel>().Result;
}
```

But the Json data that I am getting is as below:

```
"address" : [
    {
        "address1: "Via Benedetto",
        "address2: null,
        "postalCode": null
    },
    {
        "address1": null,
        "address2": "Viadanna",
        "postalCode": null
    },
    {
        "address1": null,
        "address2": null,
        "postalCode": "01234"
    }
 ]
```

It is returning a List of List. It should return only a single List

I am expecting this:

```
"address" : [ 
    { 
       "address1: "Via Benedetto", 
       "address2": "Viadanna", 
       "postalCode": "01234" 
    } 
]
```

Comment: That json is only a single dimension array or list. So what is the problem here? That is not a nested array at all.

Comment: I am expecting this result:

     "address" : [
     {
        "address1: "Via Benedetto",
        "address2": "Viadanna",
        "postalCode": "01234"
       },
     ]

Comment: That is what you have posted, so again, what is the actual issue?

Comment: If you are receiving a _different_ json, can you please post that in your question.

Comment: Please make sure you want to return 'Address' type of object and not 'AddressModel'. Your api is returning AdressModel and the json you shared is correct considering return type.

Comment: @PrasadBhokare - I want to return 'AddressModel' as it contains different Models like 'Address', 'Components', etc. 
I havent shown 'Components' in this question.

Comment: @DevP Pls show _service.GetAddressById  code.

Comment: @serge it is mentioned in the question- public AddressModel GetAddressById(string id) {}. client uri is the third-party url

Comment: What is the raw json look like from the 3rd party api?

Comment: @Mike `"address" : [ { "address1: "Via Benedetto", "address2": "Viadanna", "postalCode": "01234" } ]`

Answer (score 0):

try this ( using Newtonsoft.Json )

```
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
var stringData =  response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AddressModel>(stringData);
}
```